# MySQL event using PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute MySQL event using a PHP script. I just try to insert two fields of data in to a table when I execute the PHP script with the event call "joy" in the database but there are no data inserted in the table when I call the event.

My PHP script is:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$insertquery="CREATE EVENT joy
    ON SCHEDULE  AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE
    DO
      BEGIN
        insert into tri (name,email) values ('swapan','swapan@mail.com');

      END";

 mysql_query($insertquery) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: You can't do that with the deprecated mysql_* functions. These are more than one statement, so you've got to use mysqli or PDO with multiquery statements, if you want to do this with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mysqli_query()` rather than `mysql_query()`. This is because your SQL contians more than one query line and `mysql_query()` doesn't support this.

Additionally, `mysql_` functions are deprecated, and you should now use `mysqli_`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php for info on the mysqli functions, and also take a look at Oracle's article about converting from mysql to mysqli https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You should use mysqli instead of mysql, other than that you can test it through phpmyadmin or mysql command line , 
and by Using SHOW PROCESSLIST you can check whether it is started. If not, run the command

`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

Comment: i am do this before event is enable on server any other suggestion?